# Is it possible to keep only one evolution file for two databases in Play! framework?

Tags: database, scala, playframework

I work with Play! Scala framework 2.4 and I have two databases that are the same (one is a replication on the other for testing purpose). So far I have two evolution files (1.sql) but is there a solution allowing to use only one?

By the way, a solution that would be very helpful for some other cases would be the possibility to import a snippet of sql code inside evolution files, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be simpler to use the `H2 in-memory` database? Just have the test database settings (in `application.conf`) commented out and switch between the two.

Unless there's a particular reason why you'd need to run the test database and the live database in parallel, then that's probably the simpler solution.

Comment: The reason is that I use Postgis (with PostgreSQL) and some other extensions that I didn't manage to make work with a H2 in-memory database and I finally prefer to be sure to have the exact same behavior between the two databases.